# Linking 2 docker containers in chef recipe

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, docker-container

I am trying to achieve what the command does using chef recipe:

```
docker run -d --name=nginx --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /etc/test/test.cert:/etc/test/test.cert -v /etc/test/test.key:/etc/test/test.key -v /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx_ssl_conf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf --link=rancher-server nginx
```

This is what I have come up with so far. But I am still unable to link the two containers:

```
docker_image 'nginx' do
  tag 'latest'
  action :pull
end

docker_container 'my_nginx' do
  repo 'nginx'
  tag 'latest'
  port ['80:80', '443:443']
  volumes [ '/etc/test/test.cert:/etc/test/test.cert', '/etc/test/test.key:/etc/test/test.key', '/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx_ssl_conf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' ]
  links ['rancher-server:nginx']
  subscribes :run, 'docker_image[nginx]'
end
```

Any thoughts ? suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`links`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker/blob/50155cd52a36d6b0b8ae58ea840e76e421b22adc/libraries/docker_container.rb#L42) property which takes an array of links. There is an example [in the README](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker/blob/50155cd52a36d6b0b8ae58ea840e76e421b22adc/README.md) if you search for "Manage container links".

Comment: I don't see any change, can you be more specific?

Comment: Ahh, there it is.

Comment: That does not seem to work. When i run "docker ps -a", the status of nginx container is "Exited (1) 26 seconds ago"